# What are the friendly/rich URLs in Google Search result snippets called?

Tags: google-search, url, search-results

When searching content on Google, I sometimes see a neatly organized location of the document, instead of the regular URLs we see everyday.

After a solid hour of searching about this feature, I couldn't find the answer to my question. Can you please clarify what is this feature called, and optionally guide me on creating something like this for my website?

[image: Google Shows custom structured URLs for some search results.]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is **Google's Breadcrumb Markup**, that renders this in the google search result rich snippet.

More information can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver! I just wonder why they have named this feature 'Breadcrumb Markup', I see no resembles. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft "Breadcrumb" is the general term for this sort of history/hierarchy trail when used in UI design (you'll often see it at the top of a web page, something like "Your account > Your Orders > Order 127b") The term comes from a fairy tale (Hansel and Gretel? at least in some variations?) where the children left a trail of bread crumbs in order to find their way home.

This particular use case is slightly different, but definitely connected: it's purely hierarchical rather than showing browsing history, but at this point that's fairly common of "breadcrumbs" within websites as well.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft because that sort of navigation is called "breadcrumbs"; each section between the divider arrows is a "breadcrumb" and you can "follow" them (a la Hansel & Gretel) from the specific page you're looking at back to the home page. I think the idea here is that if you get a result for a specific item but you want to see the category, you can use the breadcrumbs to easily "back-navigate" to the category listing, etc. EDIT: sniped by Amadeus because I forgot to hit submit. Doh!

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer you are asking for is called Structured Data.  There are dozens of named tools and combined features with markup that deserve your entire attention in order to fully implement as what you have shown in picture and description.  There is a subcategory of structured data called Rich Results, which seems to match up to what you had remembered.  Even though it requires you to look from the design tool of all structured data, you can directly find the Rich Results subcategory located here [Rich Results section of Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-features#rich_results)

Please direct yourself to find the exact type of work you wish to do with the goal of creating a more quality and structured not to mention useful type of design for web or search categories and there is a portal directly located. here.  [Google Developer Website Guides](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/)